# NGX-Clipboard not working in Angular project

Tags: angular, ngx-clipboard

After installing ngx-clipboard to my project, I keep experiencing this error. Is there anything I can do to solve this issue?

Below is the error message I received:

Failed to compile.

./node_modules/ngx-clipboard/fesm2015/ngx-clipboard.mjs 290:203-215
Can't import the named export 'CommonModule' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

```
[app.module.ts][2]
```

Comment: Could you share your app.module.ts please? (or the module you want use clipboard)

Comment: I am finding it hard to edit my question

Comment: You have to just copy & paste and use {} to format your code in your answer.

Comment: Here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vm7vns?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts